# import jsp page from different web application

Tags: jsp, import, server

I tried to **imptor a jsp** page deployed in a **different server**

```
<c:import url"http://192.168.1.204:9082/ReportingPortal/apps/dashboards.jsp" />
```

but it read it as it is local , it causes no css,js files problem ! also it doesnt show anything because in `dashboards.jsp` im displaying pages from DB with login from session. I want to just **load it** not to run it again in this server.
Is there any other solution ?

Comment: i tried visiting that url but it wont load?

Comment: !!! its local url

Comment: ah right, should have looked closer. I'm quite sure you have to configure your dev server to allow outbound and inbound local connections before being able to do it like that.